# Refused to display website in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny' in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, iframe, ionic3, x-frame-options

I am trying to load this https://www.shopify.in/website website using iframe but it gives me below error:

> Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options'
>   to 'DENY'

In html:

```
<iframe class='webPage' name="samplePage" [src]="myURL"></iframe>
```

In ts:

```
export class HomePage {
  myURL: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

  }

  initialize = () => {
    this.myURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.shopify.in/website');

  };

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.initialize();
  }

}
```

Then i have tried with jquery. The error is gone but website is not loaded also.

in html:

```
<div id="loadExternalURL" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```

in ts:

```
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  initialize = () => {
    $('#loadExternalURL').load('https://www.shopify.in/website');
  };

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.initialize();
  }

}
```

How to load this website in the iframe?

Comment: Any solution for this question? I have the same problem also

Comment: No solution till now. May be, it's not possible because of the security issue,